# shrink img to fit a div with a sidebar

Tags: css, image, css-float

I'm working on an old website for someone and can't understand something with it's css:

I have a div the contains the page (article) content, which includes of course some images. in the top of the div there's another div, with extra information about the article. this second div is floated to the left.

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="lefttable"> //floated to the left
  //some information here
  </div>

  //content here, including images
</div>
```

somehow the imgs inside the content are full sized even on the top of the page, and where they supposed to be beside the `lefttable` div, they jump beneath it.

here a print-screen: https://snag.gy/qFChjB.jpg

and the page itself: http://www.bayadaim.org.il/95b

Thanks,
Itamar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some jQuery I found the way. It is not responsive, but neither this theme I'm editing - so it's good enough for me. And of course anyone who wants to develop it, is very welcome to do so.

---

### CSS Part

Set width for all the images wrapper (`wp-caption`) to the width of the main content div where it is narrower, next to the floating div.

```
#content .wp-caption {
    width: 66%;
}
```

### jQuery Part

```
//make all images in posts 100% width except images next to the left table
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var h = jQuery(".lefttable").height(); //get left table height

        jQuery('.entry-content .wp-caption').each(function(){ //loop through all .wp-captions in the content
            jQuery(this).removeAttr('style') //remove any disturbing inline styles. optional.
            var p = jQuery(this).position(); //get each .wp-caption position
            var top = p.top; //top position
            if(top > h){ //if .wp-caption is below .lefttable
                jQuery(this).css("width", "initial") //change .wp-caption width to original (or anything you like)
            }
        });
});
```

That's it. I hope someone could benefit from that.
Itamar

Answer (score 1):

The parent of your image has

- an inline style rule of `width: 970px`
- `wp-caption` and `aligncenter` classes which mean:
- - `width: 650px !important` from `style.css:1271`
- - `display: block;` from `style.css:1257`.

All the above rules forbid your element from displaying inline, side by side with the floating content that precedes it.

You need to give the parent element of your image a width that compensates the width of the floating content responsively (you can do that using `max-width` and `calc`, provided that the page container has `position:relative`, which it does) and also you need to set it's `display` to either `inline`, `inline-block` or `inline-flex`. I recommend `inline-block`.

That's the theory.
In practice, for your very specific case, you also need to compensate for some padding/margin of the left-floating elements. Here's the CSS:

```
#post-34917 #attachment_34937 {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: calc(100% - 220px);
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
#content .aligncenter>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 1023px) {
  #post-34917 #attachment_34937 {
    max-width: calc(100% - 170px);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot - it looks like the right direction, but not yet perfect. I've applied the changes you suggested on the `wp-caoption` class, which wraps every img in the article, so no all the images are smaller in 200px, instead of only those which are beside the `lefttable`.

Comment: You should not apply those rules to `.wp-caption`, because they will apply to **all the captions** (hence all the images) in your website. You have two options: 1) use the `id`s as CSS selectors, like I did (`#post-34917 #attachment_34937`) or 2) put the CSS rules in a special class and use it in your selector (i.e.: `#content .wp-caption.yourCustomClassName`) and apply `.yourCustomClassName` to the captions you want shrinked.

Comment: I understand. I'm looking for a way to design the page and its elements in a way I won't have to manually style the images, can you think of a way to achieve it?

Comment: EDIT: I'm thinking about adding some jquery to it. something like: check all .wp-caption position in the parent div, if position is more than .lefttable height - add some class.

Comment: You don't want to go there. Define `position`. After that, define `position` for each possible combination of device width + device height, a.k.a *responsively*. Responsiveness via javascript is a nightmare. The simple/good/maintainable way to go about this is one of these: a) define a custom class to apply on the elements that need to shrink. b) wrap the first part of each page's content in a container that floats side by side with your left-floating box - this container should hold enough content to match the floating boxes; or... c) move the floating boxes outside of the page content box.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) and [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```css
.lefttable {
  width:200px;
  float:left;
}
.right {
  overflow:hidden: /* to deal with floats in and out */;
}
.right img {
  max-width:calc(100% - 200px); /* where 200px is the room used by lefttable ( mind borders,  padding and margins) */
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="lefttable"> <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>   
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1200x200" />
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ituk , this is what `overflow:hidden{  does basicly. How did you use the snippet ? Can you set up a full example that shows your issue in order to get efficient help and eventually eplanation, where or how, it works and does not ? overflow is here to deal with floats https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context